# swift 2 initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIImage'

Tags: swift2

After updating my xcode to run swift 2 it gives me these two errors which i struggle to solve.

> **Error 1** Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'String'

**Code**

```
let image : UIImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

> **Error 2** Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIImage'

**Code**

```
if let constImage = image  (Error2 display here) 
        {
            let targetWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale * UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
            let resizedImage = constImage.resize(targetWidth)

            picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                () -> Void in

                NetworkManager.sharedInstance.postImage(resizedImage, completionHandler: {
                    (error) -> () in

                    if let constError = error
                    {
                        self.showAlert(constError.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })

            })
        }
```

Comment: Swift 2 fixed a ton of poor casting that existed between Objective-C code to Swift. So your "constImage" variable is most like already guaranteed to be a UIImage and/or not an optional type so you don't need to conditionally unwrap it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code ...

```
let image : UIImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

... is going to crash if there's no `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key or if it's not an image.

From where you did get `editingInfo`? Because `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` is not available in Swift. You should use `optional func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])`.

Your second error on the following line ...

```
if let constImage = image
```

... is caused by `let image: UIImage = ...` line. Your `image` is of `UIImage` type, not `UIImage?`. Thus it's not optional and you can't use it in `if let constImage = image`. Must be `UIImage?` if you want to use it in this way. BTW there's not need to use `let image: UIImage = ...`, `let image = ...` is enough, because compiler can infer variable type from your statement.

Rewrite it to something like this.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

  guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
    // throw an error, return from your function, whatever
    return
  }
  // from now you can use `image` safely
  // it does exist and it's not optional

  let targetWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale * UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
  let resizedImage = image.resize(targetWidth)

  picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
    () -> Void in

    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.postImage(resizedImage, completionHandler: {
      (error) -> () in

      if let constError = error
      {
        self.showAlert(constError.localizedDescription)
      }
    })

  })

}
```

Following part ...

```
  guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
    // throw an error, return from your function, whatever
    return
  }
```

... does this ...

- is there a value in `info` dictionary for `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key? if no, `else {}` statement is executed,
- value is there, can I cast it to `UIImage`? if no, `else {}` statement is executed,
- now we have value from `info` successfully casted to `UIImage` and stored in `image`, `else {}` statement is not executed and our function continues.

Safe way how to get a value from dictionary of some type when dictionary value type is `AnyObject` for example.